# Supermicro super server RAID warning

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, supermicro

Hey guys sorry in advance for the noobish question.

Our company just received a brand new 6017R-WRF Supermicro superserver.  I have been tasked with getting this bad boy setup.  I am a software dev and dont much sys ad.  Im attempting to put on a fresh install of centos 6.3.  My problem is below.

When I select to install it goes to examine the hardware disks and shoots me a warning saying 
`Disks sda, sdb, sdc, sdd contains BIOS RAID metadata, but are not part of any recognized BIOS RAID sets.  Ignoring disks sda, sdb, sdc, sdd.`

I guess this is telling me to partition the drive?  Second question is can I partition the drive from the BIOS?

Comment: Do you know what type of RAID controller is in the system?

Answer (score 3):

**The warning is telling you that sda/b/c/d where part of another RAID array which left some metadata on the disks themselves**. They where probably used in another RAID system (maybe only for testing).

The new server very intelligently skip these disks, as they may contain valuable data. If you are sure that these disks do NOT contain valuable data, you can enter in the array configuration module and re-initialize them (this operation basically overwrite the old metadata with the new ones).

If you have the slightest doubt about what the drives contain, please stop here and try hard do understand what is stored on these disks. If you can, do a backup of each disk.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you for that.  I know there is nothing of importance on the disks.  How would I distort the hardware disk arrays?

Comment: During boot, you should be able to enter in the RAID bios setup screen. From here, you can reinitialize the disks/array, wiping previous metadata.